# Debug in the Orchestration and in the map

Tags: debugging, biztalk, visual-studio-debugging

i have a map that does not work properly.
I have mapped a field from a my brand new schema into a canonical schema, but the problem is that in the canonical there is a field that is not valorized (but it results correclty mapped).
I want to know how it is possible.
How debugging a orchestration/map?

PS: the orchestration takes values from a MSSQL SP and then with the map construct a xml wellformatted.
PS2: Data in SQL are correctly valorized (query returns my the aspected value).

Tnx

Answer (score 3):

How to use the debugger on a BizTalk map (if you're using visual studio 2010):

- left click on the btm file you want to debug in the solution explorer window
- set the "testmap input instance" to your input file. Write the input as an xml file.
- set the "testmap output instance" to some file name where it can store the output.
- right click on the btm file in the solution explorer then choose 'debug map'
- It will open a window containing your map converted to xsl and set a breakpoint in the xsl.
- You can set breakpoints and view values in the xsl just as if you were debugging regular C# code.
- It will open a second window that will contain the output file as it constructs it.

[image]